# Counting problem to find maximum number of possible passwords

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Let S={a--z, 0--9} be the set of characters(lower case a through z) and the digits 0 through 9
I need to form a password of length 8 in which two of them must be digits. How many possible passwords can I create?

Here is what I came up with but im not positive it is correct.

```
p2 = 8C2 *10^2 * 26^6
p3 = 8C3 * 10^3 * 26^5
p4 = 8C4 * 10^4 * 26^4
p5 = 8C5 * 10^5 * 26^3
p6 = 8C6 * 10^6 * 26^2
p7 = 8C7 * 10^7 * 26^1
p8 = 8C8 * 10^8 * 26^0
and then add all the results up and thats the answer?
```

Comment: Before I send an answer, are you asking that  exactly 2 must be numbers because your work is considering atleast 2

Comment: If you wish to count passwords of length $8$ with at least two digits, then your work is correct.  You could check your answer by subtracting the number of passwords with at most one digit from the total number of eight-character passwords you could form using the $36$ available characters.

Comment: @JackGallagher yes its at least two digits

Comment: I have read the comments after posting my answer... @N.F.Taussig comment sums up my answer and probably is the fastest approach

Comment: please don't create passwords with both 1 and l in the alphabet. If you can't tell what those characters are, that's why! My password generator excludes 0, 1, O, I and l from the alphabet.

Answer (score 3):

Total number of passwords with no constraints is $36^{8}$

Now, total number of passwords with no numbers is $26^8$
Similarly, number of passwords with no numbers is $8 \choose 1$ $\cdot$ $10 \cdot 26^8$

Therefore, the total number of possible passwords is $36^{8}-26^8-$$8 \choose 1$ $\cdot$ $10 \cdot 26^8$

Answer (score 3):

Total number of passwords $36^8$

Passwords with no numbers $26^8$

Passwords with one number $8*10*26^7$

Number of possible with at least two numbers: $36^8 -26^8 -  8*10*26^7$